# C++ expected `)' before ';' token expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, templates, g++, dev-c++, typename

Hello there I am iplementingh a binary tree based on an underlying array.

My project is comprises a set of c++ files and the makefile for generating the compilation.

I am using g++ provided with DEV-C++ 4.9.9.2.

Upon launching compilation I get the following two set of errors.

AlberoBinariov.h: In member function `bool AlberoBinariov<T>::figlioSinistroVuoto(typename Alberoa<T, int>::posizioneNodo)':
AlberoBinariov.h:198: error: expected`)' before ';' token
AlberoBinariov.h:198: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
AlberoBinariov.h:198: error: expected `;' before ')' token

AlberoBinariov.h: In member function `bool AlberoBinariov<T>::figlioDestroVuoto(typename Alberoa<T, int>::posizioneNodo)':
AlberoBinariov.h:204: error: expected`)' before ';' token
AlberoBinariov.h:204: error: expected `)' before ';' token
AlberoBinariov.h:204: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
AlberoBinariov.h:204: error: expected`;' before ')' token

Interested portions of code are provided below:

```
      template <class T>
      bool AlberoBinariov<T>::figlioSinistroVuoto(posizioneNodo p)
      {
          return (figlioSinistro(p)==(posizioneNodo)P_NULL); //line 198
      }

      template <class T>
      bool AlberoBinariov<T>::figlioDestroVuoto(posizioneNodo p)
      {
           return (figlioDestro(p)==((posizioneNodo)P_NULL)); //line 204
      }
```

also for your convenince I have included the full source code at the link below.

https://filetea.me/t1sc3e60

Can you please let me know? thanks you in advance for your time. I look forward to hear from you.

Kind regards,
Gerald

PS: P_NULL is a NULL pointer constant declared in the Constants.h file.

Comment: All those hungarianreallylongnames are pretty hard to read :-( Try making a representative code example using only names like "foo", "bar" and "src"...

Comment: I imagined that. Should be better if I had chosen English names for variables. However since the project comprices some thousand lines of code and a few files, it would be very hard for me to rename all names in all files. I thinks we can get to the solution easier and sooner if you try to compile the code yourself. Just ask me what does the portions of code you need to understand I and will posta the answer. sorry I know it is a pain :)

Comment: And please update your IDE/compiler/debugger too: https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/?source=frontpage&position=7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 individual right parenthesis without their corresponding left parenthesis:

```
return (figlioDestro(p) == ((posizioneNodo)P_NULL)) /* -> */ )));
```

Change it to this:

```
return (figlioDestro(p) == ( (posizioneNodo)P_NULL ));
```

Comment: ok thanks for pointing that out. I had introduced those extra )) parenthesis while trying to fix the problem. I have removed them both from the question and the source code available through the link. however I still get the same error...

Comment: @geraldCelente You're still getting an error? Is it same error message on the same line? How is `posizioneNodo` defined? Is it a `typedef`? A class? ...?

Comment: @David posizione Nodo is defined in the class declaration  typedef typename AlberoBinarioa<T ,int>::posizioneNodo posizioneNodo;

Comment: @geraldCelente Is the error you're getting the same error you show in the question?

Comment: @geraldCelente And what is `P_NULL`? Is it a macro? If it is then you must make sure that the text that gets placed into `P_NULL` doesn't conflict with any thing.

Comment: @David P_NULL is a NULL array constant declared in the Constants.h file. It is used to indicate that a tree Node does not cointain and a left or right child. Basecally what the figlioSinistroVuoto (in English EmplyLeftChild) and figlioDestroVuoto (EmptyRightChild) return true or false depending on the fact that p node left/right child is empty or not.

Comment: @geraldCelente Visually, there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown and I can't for the life of me find out what it is. When you receive errors like `expected primary expression before` it usually denotes a syntax error, which are commonly caused by misplaced parenthesis and improperly used macros. It can also be caused by not putting the keyword `typename` where it is required (I thought that might be the problem but then I saw you were already using `typename` in the `posizioneNodo` typedef). Maybe there's some part of the code that you haven't showed us that's causing the problem?

Comment: @David I think the best bet is that you try to compile the project yourself with the makefile provided. I am using dev-c++ 4.9.9.2 - of course if that is not asking to much of you. You can get the full source code from https://filetea.me/t1sdccc7 - I hope that is not asking too much of you... :)))

Comment: @geraldCelente I'm getting a lot more errors than usual. There's a void function from which you are returning. What did you mean to be the return value of this function -- http://gyazo.com/a015a70665f855cd2485e034a6a0a739

Comment: @David Hello David, sorry to keep you waiting. I had to get some sleep yesterday. That's why have not replied so far.  Anyway I have now created a dev-cpp project with main and have include it with the project. When comiling it gives me the error i was getting in the beginning. You can get it from https://filetea.me/t1sc3e60 . PS: I really appreciate the time you have been spending on fixing my problem. Thank you very much. :))

Comment: @geraldCelente I'm not able to get on that site... :)